# How to align Card.Section components in MS Fluent UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, alignment, fluent-ui

I have Card with 2 Card.Sections. I'm trying to align the second one to far right however nothing works for me. I tried:

1. Setting sections as `flex` and assigning `marginLeft: auto` for the second one
2. Setting Card `position: relative`, then adding `float: right` to the second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue today, here's how I solved it:

```
<Card horizontal tokens={cardTokens}>
  <Card.Section>
    <Checkbox
      label="todo status"
    />
  </Card.Section>
  <Card.Item grow={1}>
    <span />
  </Card.Item>
  <Card.Section styles={footerCardSectionStyles}>
    <Icon iconName="Delete" />
  </Card.Section>
</Card>
```

As you can see I used

```
 <Card.Item grow={1}>
   <span />
 </Card.Item>
```

between the two `Card.Section`s this is inserting an element with the remaining width thus pushing the second `Card.Section` to the end.

Comment: Hey, it works! How did you find it out? I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-ui-fabric-react/istackprops?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest#grow but based on description this is some other property... and this is for Stacks, not Cards.
I also couldn't find that on https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/card. Yea, there's 'grow' listed but there's no description and I don't see any further reference links on their site.

Comment: @VIPPER I actually found this in a weird way. I noticed that the vertical card example in the docs has the last `card.section` at the end so I looked into its code and found that. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/card.